# safari z-index and overflow not working

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

i have a problem with z-index blocks in safari

```
http://rhino.shahumyanmedia.com/
```

this website is working fine in other browser, but the top 4 circle blocks don't displaying properly, the images in the block are getting out of block, although i have given the overflow:hidden, and z-index to main block and image

> Note:i don't like to make images as background

here is my style

```
.add-border {
border-radius: 300px;
-moz-border-radius: 300px;
-o-border-radius: 300px;
-webkit-border-radius: 300px;
border: 8px solid rgba(20, 172, 225, 0.3);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 5;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.service-img img {
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-transition: all 0.5s ease;
z-index: -1;
border-radius: 300px;
-moz-border-radius: 300px;
-o-border-radius: 300px;
-webkit-border-radius: 300px;
}
.service a {
border-radius: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
z-index: 20;
-moz-border-radius: 300px;
-o-border-radius: 300px;
-webkit-border-radius: 300px;
}




   <div class="service-img">
       <a href="http://rhino.shahumyanmedia.com/category/%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%be/">
   <img src="http://rhino.shahumyanmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/face1.png" alt="лицо"/>
      <div class="add-border"></div>

</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code here. As soon as the issue is fixed, this question becomes useless for future reference.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. Thanks.

Comment: Everything works fine here